# Animated gif don't work with createImage () in P5.js?

Tags: processing, gif, p5.js

I'm trying to create an animated gif to display within an image created with createImage () but it apparently doesn't work with the great new gif update made for p5.js?
Is this possible? Or am I forgetting something?

```
let img, gif;

function preload() {
  gif = loadImage('assets/test.gif');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(960, 540);
  img = createImage(320, 180);
}

function draw() {
  img.image(gif,0,0);
}
```

Comment: I can't speak for p5, but in Processing you had to use a library to display gifs.

Comment: They have recently incorporated the excellent functionality of displaying animated gifs on p5, which is great. Apparently some adjustments are still missing, which are beyond my current knowledge and skills.

Comment: That's cool. Take a look at my answer, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this post](https://editor.p5js.org/kjhollen/sketches/S1bVzeF8Z) can help you.

The problems I see with your code are

1. you're using `loadImage` instead of `createImage` for the gif
2. and you're using `img.image(...)` to display the gif, eventhough you are only supposed to **set the position** of the image in draw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you are referring to the way of displaying animated gif with P5.Element which creates an element in the DOM and my question is actually about the current functionality of doing it with P5.Image.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Guess I don't know that much about p5.js after all. Have you considered posting on the official Processing forum?